# Random choice not working properly

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, random

```
foo = ['hello', 'hi', 'sup', 'hey', 'yo']
def main():
    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    with open('links.txt', 'r') as f:
        urls = []
        for url in f:
            rand = random.choice(foo)
            driver.get(url)
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200)")
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_class_name('comment-simplebox-renderer-collapsed-content').click()
                actions.send_keys(rand)
                actions.perform()
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="comment-simplebox"]/div[3]/div[2]/button[2]""").click()
                time.sleep(3)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass
```

Instead of picking a random string I have in the foo list, it instead picks a random string the first time, the second time it just picks the first string and adds another random string to that. So it just adds strings to the rand variable instead of overwriting it. How can I solve this?

I tried moving up the rand variable but that didn't work.

Comment: `random.choice` works. Your code doesn't. Where is `foo` declared? a [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: It's decalred at the top of my program.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the definition of `foo`.

Comment: and also, if you can remove from your code all the non-related lines - it will help creating focus on the issue you're having

Comment: `actions.send_keys(rand)` will keep sending a new random choice. You may need to use `actions.send_keys(keys.BACKSPACE)` for each character you previously sent to erase the original random choice.

Comment: Added the foo list

Comment: Oliver, after it pasted the random string it clicks on a button. So it's always a new textbox it writes it in.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `random.choice`.

You are misusing the [`ActionChains`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) object:

> When you call methods for actions on the ActionChains object, the actions are stored in a queue in the ActionChains object. When you call perform(), the events are fired in the order they are queued up.

Every time you call `actions.send_keys(rand)` you add more actions to the queue.  Calling `actions.perform()` doesn't clear the queue of actions.

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Comment: @DanielCarlsson: Do one of: (1) Skip using `ActionChains` altogether and do `driver.find_element_by_whatever(whatever).send_keys(rand)`. (2) Move `actions = ActionChains(driver)` inside your for-loop.  (3) Call `actions.reset_actions()` after `actions.perform()`. (I'm not certain about `reset_actions()`.  The docs says it "clears actions that are already stored on the remote end."  That makes it sounds like it may empty the queue of actions.  If not, options 1 and 2 will surely work.)